# Programming Microcontrollers

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, microcontroller

I have taken a class in University about programming microcontrollers in Assembly. We had a microcontroller that was given to us through the school, and the IDE to program the microcontroller.

So is it possible to grab any random circuit with a microcontroller (eg. TV remote) and program the controller? I have looked for quite a while online and have not found any information regarding this.

Comment: If you can find out the actual type of processor, and know how the hardware attached to it works, and can find out the assembler for it (not all microcontrollers use the same assembler), you may be able to reprogram it. It would require a little more than casual knowledge, though.

Comment: So I would need the schematic, and know the type of controller?

Comment: It is getting quite rare, unbeknownst to academia, everybody uses a C compiler these days.  A cross-compiler.  Keil is the 20 pound gorilla, there's open source tooling too.  And no, it is never ever random.

Comment: @ChaseErnst: yes, of course. Hardware can vary a lot.

Comment: Like Rudy said, it's possible if you know the details of the hardware. However I'd suggest starting from something like Arduino rather than opening up your TV remote. The arduino community has tonnes of materials which will make your learning easier. You will find not only the schematic of the boards, but also bootloaders, example codes, demo applications that actually work and etc. And I'd be surprised if you can find such details for your TV remote.

Comment: Mass produced stuff is often special purpose, since it is cheaper to make one chip that does it all rather than buy generic chips and have all of them on the board (once you reach some quantity).  So it is less and less likely to figure it out, also cheaper to get one time programmables than re-programmables so even if you do figure it out you might not be able to repurpose it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what kind of microcontroller the manufacturer used. There are a lot of [One-Time Programmable](https://www.google.com/search?q=one+time+programmable+microcontrollers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=ssl#q=one+time+programmable+microcontrollers&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&tbm=shop) microcontrollers available that you would not be able to reprogram. Thanks to @dwelch for pointing these out.

If the manufacturers used a reprogrammable microcontroller, then generally yes, you can. They may employ [lock bits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18438/49184) to prevent you from downloading and reverse-engineering the compiled code, but you should still be able to wipe and reprogram them.

Someone could use some tricks to make it more difficult, but not impossible, for you to reuse the reprogrammable chips. For example, on Atmega AVR chips, you can set a fuse that turns the RESET pin into a GPIO. The RESET pin is required for in-system reprogramming, so you would have to remove the chip from the board and [use some more complicated](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/260.html) tricks to recover the ability to reprogram the chip.

Comment: OTP one time programmable, been around for a long time, cant reprogram them...Better choice due to price, etc in mass produced items (like tv remotes, clocks, etc).

Comment: Thanks @dwelch. As soon as I saw your comment, I realized the dumb oversight I made. I'm so used to working with reprogrammable microcontrollers for school and small projects, I forgot all about the production world.

Comment: It may also be that the necessary device programming pins are not accessible or identifiable - especially on a BGA device on a multi-layer board for example.

Answer (score 2):

Microcontrollers (MCUs) are not for circuits/schematics to be grabbed into it, for those purposes FPGAs are invented where you can describe a circuit/schematic at the level of TTL logic by some languages like VHDL and Verilog. MCUs are alomost the same as general CPU, they are themselves included into an electronic circuit/schematic and interact  with outside circuit by means of communication ports, General Input Output pins, buses and interfaces.

So in order to create TV remote you don't need to repeat 100% circuit of any of them, you rather need to be focused on a target TV set, its [Infrared Format(s)](http://www.vishay.com/docs/80071/dataform.pdf). A number of them exist, just do your search.

[image]
[image]

and you just want to achieve the same functionality (but not a copying). In two words your design is: MCU connected via its own serial line to IR transceiver, e.g. [this CS8130](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/cs8130.html), but there are a lot of them from different companies, just do your search again.
[image]

Then you can send a IR command to your TV set - the series of ones and zeroes according to format used in your TV.